# Cannot read property 'init' of undefined in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming, es6-class

I am trying to integrate Twitter through React native. 
I am following the below link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-twitter-signin

While integrating I got the above issue.

```
const { RNTwitterSignIn } = NativeModules;
const Constants = {
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: '<Some twitter key>',
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: '<Some twitter consumer secret>',
};
```

While initializing RNTwitterSignIn with TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY and TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, it says that RNTwitterSignIn is undefined.

```
RNTwitterSignIn.init(Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
```

Please check my code and let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: can you `console.log(RNTwitterSignIn);`, please provide your rest of the code

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with this? I am stuck there too. It Looks like RNTwitterSignIn is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem but adding Twitter's library and framework to: Build Phases --> Link Binary with Libraries.
I also made sure I had the following (with the appropriate key and secret)in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

Objective C:

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"" consumerSecret:@""];
```

Swift:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"", consumerSecret:"")
```